# Auto-closing feedback dialog after login - how to indicate this to the user?

Tags: usability

My login dialog has four states:

- 'Form' - for actually filling in the user details
- Loading - waiting for the server response
- Failed - feedback & a retry button to take you back to the 'form'
- Success - feedback, and an okay button to close

It was correctly pointed out that the success dialog is more frustrating than useful. It's just an extra button to press. [There's some good answers here.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84369/is-a-login-successful-message-necessary)

I still want to show feedback of the success, beyond the minor changes to the UI (profile pic/user name/logout button in the bar in the top right).

The easiest thing is to simply remove the okay buttons, and close the login dialog after a small time. So, at the moment it looks like this in the success state:

[image]

And after a second it closes itself.

It works well, but I can't help but think it feels a bit strange. There's no indication to the user that this dialog is going to close in a second. How can I indicate that this is going to happen? A little countdown/progress bar animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to provide welcome message if the user is signed-up for the first time, but when the existing user is logging-in why not **direct them to their dashboard or show their profile**. That would be good enough for them of know that the **Login was Successful**. I don't think that success feedback is helping users in any way other than killing their few seconds.

Success messages are helpful in scenarios such as Bank Transactions, but not for login into your account.

I won't recommend using channels just because they are available; use it when they are really necessary such as for Errors and Warnings.

Comment: Didn't think of simply redirecting, that would be a simple way to change the state when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to make things more complex then they are.**

1 second is not long enough to justify informing the user about that. 
The user will see that the dialog closes itself after 1 second, where is the problem? Its not like he's staring at that overlay for 30 seconds wondering what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

A notification for a successful login is unneccessary because it's the expected outcome.
The post you linked contains a very detailed answer to your question, in particular this passage:

> Keep notifications for what really matters because it may fail or if you do not have any other PERMANENT feedback of their result (when application state is clearly changed - and it MUST be clear when you're logged in - message is just redundant). [...] Moreover, unnecessary messages slow down UX experience, break workflow and reduce user attention to meaningful messages (errors, alerts or important notifications).
>   - Adriano Repetti

The reason it feels strange to use your proposal is because it's both unusual and unpredictable. Self closing notifications are not very helpful because you cannot predict how fast a user will see and read the message before it disappears. This is one of the reasons you normally see notifications with a close button, you keep the control with the user and you only show them notifications that matter. You don't want to run the risk that the user starts to disregard messages because they seem unimportant to them.

If it's unclear to your user that they're in a logged-in state, perhaps take another look at the design itself?

Answer (score 0):

In my oponion you dont want to have a dialog what automatically closes without the option for the user to close it manually. The user should always be in control and it can be frustrating if you have to watch a dialog which you cant close yourself.